# How can I add JSON data into my mysql data if possible how can i create a loop for it

Tags: php, json, loops

I am working with an api which let me fetch it's game details as a json file, I have all the game ids but cannot convert it to go into my msql database and also can oyu tell me that how can I create a loop of all the ids to make work automatically. Here is the code I have made so far

```
//Get the id of the game
$gameid = "gu45bh84p";

//Call the api
$json=file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/?fetch=$gameid");

$details=json_decode($json);

//Check if respose contains the game information
if($details->Response=='True')
{  
//Print the game information
echo "game-ID : ".$details->gameID.'<br>';
echo "Title : ".$details->Title.'<br>';
echo "Year : ".$details->Year.'<br>';
echo "Poster Image Path: ".$details->Poster.'<br>';
echo "Released Date: ".$details->Released.'<br>';
echo "Genre : ".$details->Genre.'<br>';
echo "Language : ".$details->Language.'<br>';
echo "Country : ".$details->Country.'<br>';

}
//Show message if the game information is not returned by API
else
{
     echo "Game information not available.Please confirm game id";
}
```

Comment: `$details->Whatever` will not work ... use `$details['Whatever']`

Comment: @EugenRieck:  You know this how?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Because the return value of `json_decode()` is not an object, but an associative array.

Comment: @EugenRieck: No, it is not.

Comment: I rather wonder who would upvote this "write me code" question

Comment: @EugenRieck not always, only when you pass the second parameter as `true` which is not the case here

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just so as not to cause confusion, json_decode does return an object by default.  You can explicitly ask it to return an associate array instead by passing **true** as it's second parameter.

To answer the question, you've got an object returned, and it appears you can already retrieve the data from it and display it on your page.  So if you want the data in your database, just pass those values into your database insert statement instead.